# Quick mass-updating a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<int, int>` and would like to update certain elements all at once based on their current values, e.g. changing all elements with value 10 to having value 14 or something.

I imagined this would be easy with some LINQ/lambda stuff but it doesn't appear to be as simple as I thought. My current approach is this:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> kvps = dictionary.Where(d => d.Value == oldValue).ToList();
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in kvps)
{
   dictionary[KeyValuePair.Key] = newValue;
}
```

The problem is that `dictionary` is pretty big (hundreds of thousands of elements) and I'm running this code in a loop thousands of times, so it's incredibly slow. There must be a better way...

Comment: what if you generate an new dictionary ?

Comment: @JonH: Then it will be even slower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be the wrong data structure.  You are attempting to look up dictionary entries based on their values which is the reverse of the usual pattern.  Maybe you could store Sets of keys that currently map to certain values.  Then you could quickly move these sets around instead of updating each entry separately.

Comment: That then makes look-up by key slower though, doesn't it?

Comment: I think this was my original approach but it didn't work so well, probably because of the algorithm I used, so I'll give it another shot.

Comment: @Jeff: Yes.  If that's relevant, you could take the middle ground and use both, wrapped up in a class.  You could use the sets to get the keys for the mass value-updating, and you could use the dictionary normally, while remembering to keep the sets in sync.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider writing your own collection type to achieve this whereby keys with the same value actually share the same value instance such that changing it in one place changes it for all keys.

Something like the following (obviously, lots of code omitted here - just for illustrative purposes):

```
public class SharedValueDictionary : IDictionary<int, int>
{
   private List<MyValueObject> values;

   private Dictionary<int, MyValueObject> keys;

   // Now, when you add a new key/value pair, you actually
   // look in the values collection to see if that value already
   // exists. If it does, you add an entry to keys that points to that existing object
   // otherwise you create a new MyValueObject to wrap the value and add entries to
   // both collections.
}
```

This scenario would require multiple versions of `Add` and `Remove` to allow for changing all keys with the same value, changing only one key of a set to be a new value, removing all keys with the same value and removing just one key from a value set. It shouldn't be difficult to code for these scenarios as and when needed.

Comment: The problem with this approach is what if one key-value pair needs to be updated and the another pair, with the same value, does not?

Comment: @Paulo Santos - If one changed the other would automatically change.

Comment: I understood the approach Jeff suggested, but the issue remains. Imagine that we have a pair X:10 and Y:10, for instance, and the X needs to be updated to, say, 15, but not the Y. The collection Jeff suggested would change both X and Y to the same value, always.

Comment: @Paulo: In that scenario, you'd need a different method than Add on your collection that allowed you to specify that's the behaviour you want. That alternative add would transfer the target of the key to a new value object rather than change its existing value object.

Comment: At the start of the function all values in the dictionary have different values, so I don't think this would be any more efficient. (Perhaps this is indicative that my choice of collection type is not the best.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a new dictionary:

`d = d.ToDictionary(w => w.Key, w => w.Value == 10 ? 14 : w.Value)`

Comment: Cool idea; unfortunately it seems to run even slower.

Comment: @Andrew Arnold - Well remember it is a lambda :), your for loop may be the only option I can think of for quick and dirty.  Or consider what @Jeff Yates suggested.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem that the O.P. is having, because under the hood the dictionary will cycle through the elements and add the key-value pair to the new object, one by one.

Comment: @Paulo Santos - I understand that, hence my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing that everybody must be missing is that it is exceeeeedingly trivial:

```
List<int> keys = dictionary.Keys.Where(d => d == oldValue);
```

You are *NOT* looking up keys by value (as has been offered by others). 
Instead, `keys.SingleOrDefault()` will now by definition return the single key that equals `oldValue` if it exists in the dictionary. So the whole code should simplify to

```
if (dictionary.ContainsKey(oldValue))
   dictionary[key] = newValue;
```

That is quick. Now I'm a little concerned that this might indeed *not* be what the OP intended, but it *is* what he had written. So if the existing code does what he needs, he will now have a highly performant version of the same :)

Comment: No, actually; `ContainsKey` will find all elements in the dictionary where the *key* is `oldValue`; I want the elements where the *value* is `oldValue`.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure my code in the question doesn't actually reflect what I meant to say.

Comment: Sorry I missed that by only looking at the lambda predicate - silly me

Answer (score 0):

After the edit, this seems an immediate improvement:

```
foreach (var kvp in dictionary.Where(d => d.Value == oldValue))
{
   kvp.Value = newValue;
}
```

I'm pretty sure you can update the kvp directly, as long as the key isn't changed

Comment: I've already tried this, and you can't do it. The `Value` property is read-only. The only way to change it is by going through the key.

Comment: Right I just found that out by trying to get this in a profiler :)